# guide for new method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comments

how can I add a guide  box for my Own new method in JavaScript
[for example, this picture has a guide box for slice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gt8S.png)

Comment: I wonder if JsDoc is at all relevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Your comment format is the key.***

1. please ensure your comments will be inside /* My Comments */
   [image]
2. Now see the result.
   [image]

For complex comments:
[image]